# From the iOS chrome app to my app and back chrome on the same tab

Tags: ios, iphone, google-chrome, safari, callback

The flow I am trying to do here is as follows:

1. user visits a page in my webapp with the chrome iOS app
2. user clicks a login link which starts a session and shows a link with an url scheme my iOS app can handle
3. user clicks that link and my iOS app opens up
4. my iOS app does it thing ( it authenticates the user )
5. when finished, I would like to be able to get the user back to the chrome iOS app on the same tab he started from. This tab is polling my server every x seconds to see if my iOS app has finished.

Is this possible? I can open up the chrome app easily just by using the googlechromes url scheme but this opens up a new tab. I need the user to land on the same tab

Similary for the safari app, I can get the same behaviour by using the https url scheme to open up safari.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems it is not possible as explained here: [Open safari in same tab from iPhone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551644/open-safari-in-same-tab-from-iphone-application?rq=1)

I guess it makes sense not allowing this, so other apps cannot manipulate your current open tabs.