# Returning focus / task switching to Safari from within an iOS application

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, safari

We have what I think is a fairly unusual set of requirements for a mobile web application. We want to be able to have the following flow:

- User uses our web app to perform some tasks (the web app is also meant for use on a desktop)
- They perform an operation that requires passing control to a native iOS application to communicate with some hardware (we'll be using URI handlers for this)
- The native iOS application does its thing (potentially communicating to its own backend), and eventually completes its process
- We want to pass control from the iOS app BACK TO our web app

Now, as I see it we have a few options:

1. We open a new tab in safari using something like `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url]`

   - The new tab can then communicate with the old tab "somehow" (localstorage?) and have the old tab close itself
   - The same, but the new tab closes itself and we rely on the old tab being the 'last focused'
2. We have the user themselves switch control back to our web app
3. There is some other way to just 'switch control' back to safari without opening a new tab

Obviously (3) is our preferred option but I haven't been able to identify any way with the public APIs to allow this to happen. What is slightly confusing is that safari and google maps on iOS 7 seems to let you do just this. You can:

- Google for an address
- Click the map that comes up, which opens Google Maps
- Google Maps shows a 'return to safari' bar at the top of the app
- Clicking that transfers focus back to safari without appearing to open a new tab.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Cheers.

Comment: +1 Although [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551644/open-safari-in-same-tab-from-iphone-application) is pretty similar, I agree with You that the Google Maps app actually does it.